# Winsock always finding connection

Tags: c++, udp

I am trying to send a string over a udp socket in c++. Whenever i run this code, it always prints connection found infinitely. What am i doing wrong here? I'm not sure what it is seeing as a connection being made to it while listening or if something in my listening code is wrong? Any help would be appreciated :)

```
void main()

{
long sucessful;
WSAData WinSockData;
WORD DLLVERSION;

DLLVERSION = MAKEWORD(2, 1);

sucessful = WSAStartup(DLLVERSION, &WinSockData);

SOCKADDR_IN ADDRESS;
int cacheSize = sizeof(ADDRESS);

SOCKET sock_LISTEN;

SOCKET sock_CONNECTION;

sock_CONNECTION = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

ADDRESS.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
ADDRESS.sin_family = AF_INET;
ADDRESS.sin_port = htons(444);

sock_LISTEN = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
bind(sock_LISTEN, (SOCKADDR*)&ADDRESS, sizeof(ADDRESS));
listen(sock_LISTEN, SOMAXCONN);

for (;;) {


    if (sock_CONNECTION = accept(sock_LISTEN,NULL, NULL)) {
        cout << "connection was found \n";
        sucessful = send(sock_CONNECTION, "I SEE YOU JAVA!", 100, NULL);
    }

    }



 }
```

Comment: You don't check results of most calls. And even when you do (in case of `accept`) you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDP is connection-less, you can't call `listen()` or `accept()` on a UDP socket.  They will both fail and report `WSAEOPNOTSUPP` from `WSAGetLastError()`.

You are ignoring errors from `listen()`.

You are not testing the return value of `accept()` correctly.  When `accept()` fails, it returns `INVALID_SOCKET`, which is defined as `(SOCKET)(~0)` (aka `-1` casted to a `SOCKET`).  Any non-zero value will evaluate as true in a boolean expression, such as an `if` statement.

There is no way to detect whether a UDP listener is running before you send packets to it.  All you can do is unconditionally send packets and hope that responses are sent back.